# Подсовывается более старшая версия библиотеки несмотря на SpecificVersion=true

Tags: .net, oracle, gac

В проекте есть ссылка на oracle.dataacess v4.112.2.0 с флагом Specific version = true
Делаю билд, переношу на тестовую машину (для тестирования используется виртуальный образ клиентской машины). запускаю - запускается.
Для того, чтобы убедиться, что берется не та версия:
Иду в хранилище GAC - там лежат две версии Oracle DataAccess

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112 .......

и

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121 .......

Переименовываю тот каталог, что с 112 - приложение при запуске даже не замечает этого и запускается нормально.

Переименовываю тот каталог, что с 121 - ошибка загрузки Oracle.DataAccess

Почему .net хочет использовать более старшую версию, хотя этого не нужно? как изменить это поведение

Comment: Трусливый вариант: убежать на [Managed Driver](https://www-1.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)

Comment: @defaultlocale он вроде не поддерживает UDT (CustomTypes), что для передачи массивов вроде как критично

Comment: Различия безусловно есть и переход требует тщательного тестирования. Поэтому написал в комментарии как возможную альтернативу.

Answer (score 1):

`SpecificVersion` это свойство времени компиляции, не рантайма! Т.е. при запуске оно никакого значения при выборе версии не будет иметь.

Для того чтобы проверить какая версия референса по факту зашивается в сборку, проверьте её ILDASM или любым другим просмотрщиком сборок.

Comment: внутри в манифесте указано: 4:112:2:0

Comment: @vvsibir В конфигурационном файле binding redirect не прописаны случайно?

Comment: это в App.config'е? прошелся по таким файлам ничего редиректного не нашел. пишут что в .Net 4.5 в проектах используют авторедирект, но у нас в проектах используется 4 ClientProfile.

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь gacutil.exe для добавления удаления в GAC сборок. Удалите все кроме требуемой и убедитесь что с ней не загружается.